# Обработка checkbox элементов в php

Tags: checkbox, php

Нужна Ваша подсказка по обработке `checbox name="type[]"`
У меня есть множество `checkboxes`. Каждый из них имеет уникальный `value="Число"`, которое заносится в базу. После выбора соответствующих и нажатию "Сохранить изменения" - отмеченные флажки ложатся в базу. И при следующем просмотре, они делаются `selected` (отмеченные)
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при снятии галочек с уже выставленных ранее `checkboxes`, они обновлялись в базе и были уже `not checked`. Как быть в таком случает?

Comment: Ну при снятии обновляйте базу и рисуйте их как не-selected при следующем выводе. Т.е. делайте select перед выводом на страницу, в том же стиле, как и при том, когда, - после записи в базу, - выводите их как selected. Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: Да - вы не так поняли. Потому что checkboxes уже выводятся отмеченные. И если снять с ним выделение, то на серверную часть ничего не придет, а должно при снятии удаляться из базы

Comment: Если *"снять с них выделение"*, как вы выразились, то здесь есть два варианта (хотя для записи в базу их как selected вы ведь что-то используете? Вы ведь сами пишете - *"После выбора соответствующих и нажатию "Сохранить изменения" - отмеченные флажки ложатся в базу."*): либо SUBMIT на форме, либо используйте AJAX для посылки данных без перезагрузки страницы.
Т.е. вы же заносите их, как selected  "по нажатию" в самом начале? Ну заносите те, которые не-selected (после того, как отобразили их) опять же в базу через "Сохранить изменения"! Или стирайте что-ли - как уж заблагорассудится.

Comment: Не понимаю Вас до конца. Давайте так. У меня есть 3 отмеченные галочки. Я снимаю с них выделение и делаю сабмит. Как на серверной части обрабатывать эти снятые checkbox? Чтобы удалить их из базы по value

Comment: А поля базы тогда напишите - я же не телепат. Хотя, вы же их *как-то* заносите, как selected в начале? Т.е. для каждого элемента type[] у вас же есть свой field в таблице?? Т.е., когда вы их, - после первого *"Сохранить изменения"*, - заносите в базу, выставляете же *какие-то* значения *куда-то*? Допустим, type[0] имеет статус selected на странице (выставленный пользователем, т.е. он его *отметил*), и после нажатия *"Сохранить изменения"* вы *заносите* эти данные в таблицу как значение некоего field как 1, то после второго обновления что мешает записать туда 0?

Comment: Можете добавить атрибут в чекбокс, задавать 1 или 0 и по нему проверять какой выбран, а какой нет, тут много всего можно придумать.

Comment: Я же писал изначально, что в базу заносится значение value для каждого type[].
Структура базы такая: 
idNote IdTypeSelect
1      1
2      18
3      9
Где IdTypeSelect соответствует значению value выбранного checkbox

Answer (score 3):

При обновлении информации удаляйте все флажки из базы и проставляйте новые.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не "пробежаться" по всем элементам, и не собрать в удобное представление результат.

```
<script>
    function selected_(){
        var type = {};
        var elements = document.getElementById("box").getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            type[elements[i].value] = elements[i].checked;
        }

        //Преобразовать в удобный вид и отправить на сервер 
        alert(JSON.stringify(type));
    }
</script>
<div id="box">
    <p><input value="0" type="checkbox"></p>
    <p><input value="1" type="checkbox"></p>
    <p><input value="2" type="checkbox"></p>
    <p><input value="3" type="checkbox"></p>
    <p><input value="4" type="checkbox"></p>
</div>
<input type="button" onClick="selected_();" value="сохранить">
```

Answer (score 0):

`var check1 = $('#check1').attr('checked') ? $('#check1').attr('value') : 0;`

Вообщем, если чекбокс отмечен, переменная check1 будет содержать его значение. Если не отмечен, то check=0. На сервере проверяйте уже сами. Когда 0 - удаляйте, когда не 0, делайте что-то еще.

Это для ajax.

Comment: Если value = 0 - тогда к как я определю какой селекд удалять?

Comment: Троллингом попахивает.